# Airflow check BigQuery table size and end another operator's execution

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer-2

Using Cloud Composer (Airflow) I have a PythonOperator that inserts some data in a BigQuery table. I want to constantly check the size of this table and when it reaches a specific size to stop executing the PythonOperator that inserts data and end the DAG. Is this possible?

Comment: Can you share your PythonOperator?